# x265: I don't get full statistics per frame during encoding process

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, video-encoding, libx265

I'm using x265 on Ubuntu 12.04 server.

I'm using the command `--log-level 4` to get full statistics per frame by I only get frame rate per frame.

This is the output:

```
yuv  [info]: 560x448 fps 40000/1000 i420p8 frames 0 - 589 of 590
raw  [info]: output file: ../results_profiles_qps/H_C_ultrafast/ultrafast_2_1_3_--sao_--deblock_0:0__/H_C_560x448_40_QP17_ultrafast_2_1_3_--sao_--deblock_0:0__.bin
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 1.8+219-692e3230b505
x265 [info]: build info [Linux][GCC 4.8.1][64 bit][noasm] 8bit
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: none!
x265 [warning]: --psnr used with psy on: results will be invalid!
x265 [warning]: --tune psnr should be used if attempting to benchmark psnr!
x265 [info]: Main profile, Level-3 (Main tier)
x265 [info]: Thread pool created using 32 threads
x265 [info]: frame threads / pool features       : 3 / wpp(7 rows)
x265 [warning]: Source height < 720p; disabling lookahead-slices
x265 [info]: Coding QT: max CU size, min CU size : 64 / 16
x265 [info]: Residual QT: max TU size, max depth : 32 / 1 inter / 1 intra
x265 [info]: ME / range / subpel / merge         : dia / 57 / 0 / 2
x265 [info]: Keyframe min / max / scenecut       : 9 / 96 / 0
x265 [info]: Lookahead / bframes / badapt        : 10 / 2 / 0
x265 [info]: b-pyramid / weightp / weightb       : 1 / 0 / 0
x265 [info]: References / ref-limit  cu / depth  : 1 / 0 / 0
x265 [info]: Rate Control                        : CQP-17
x265 [info]: tools: rd=2 psy-rd=2.00 early-skip tmvp fast-intra
x265 [info]: tools: strong-intra-smoothing deblock sao
[0.2%] 1/590 frames, 3.86 fps, 13270.40 kb/s, eta 0:02:32  
[1.0%] 6/590 frames, 10.91 fps, 6471.73 kb/s, eta 0:00:53  
[2.0%] 12/590 frames, 13.75 fps, 5460.88 kb/s, eta 0:00:42  
[3.1%] 18/590 frames, 15.46 fps, 5167.98 kb/s, eta 0:00:37  
[3.7%] 22/590 frames, 15.50 fps, 4942.41 kb/s, eta 0:00:36  
[4.7%] 28/590 frames, 16.45 fps, 4841.28 kb/s, eta 0:00:34
```

I have also x265 on Centos server and using the previous command I get [debug] POC no, QP, bits, Y U V PSNR values, SSIM and lookahead levels.

This is the desirable output:

```
yuv  [info]: 560x448 fps 40000/1000 i420p8 frames 0 - 589 of 590
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 1.4+174-35d086074bb5
x265 [info]: build info [Linux][GCC 4.4.7][64 bit] 8bpp
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE Cache64
x265 [warning]: --ssim used with AQ off: results will be invalid!
x265 [warning]: --tune ssim should be used if attempting to benchmark ssim!
x265 [info]: Main profile, Level-3 (Main tier)
x265 [info]: WPP streams / frame threads / pool  : 7 / 3 / 6
x265 [info]: CTU size / RQT depth inter / intra  : 64 / 1 / 1
x265 [info]: ME / range / subpel / merge         : dia / 25 / 0 / 2
x265 [info]: Keyframe min / max / scenecut       : 9 / 96 / 0
x265 [info]: Lookahead / bframes / badapt        : 10 / 2 / 0
x265 [info]: b-pyramid / weightp / weightb / refs: 1 / 0 / 0 / 1
x265 [info]: Rate Control / AQ-Strength / CUTree : CQP-16 / 0.0 / 0
x265 [info]: tools: rd=2 early-skip deblock sao fast-intra tmvp 
x265 [debug]: POC:0 I QP 13.00(13)     330296 bits [Y: 51.91 U: 56.01 V: 56.27] [SSIM: 27.060dB]
[0.2%] 1/590 frames, 1.34 fps, 13493.12 kb/s, eta 0:07:18  
x265 [debug]: POC:3 P QP 16.00(16)     212720 bits [Y: 46.65 U: 55.09 V: 54.30] [SSIM: 21.816dB] [L0 0 ]
x265 [debug]: POC:2 B QP 17.00(17)     127592 bits [Y: 45.94 U: 55.09 V: 54.26] [SSIM: 21.003dB] [L0 0 ] [L1 3 ]
x265 [debug]: POC:1 b QP 18.00(18)      97232 bits [Y: 45.46 U: 55.09 V: 54.38] [SSIM: 20.588dB] [L0 0 ] [L1 2 3 ]
x265 [debug]: POC:6 P QP 16.00(16)     197024 bits [Y: 46.57 U: 55.09 V: 54.16] [SSIM: 21.601dB] [L0 3 ]
[0.8%] 5/590 frames, 4.81 fps, 7776.19 kb/s, eta 0:02:01  
x265 [debug]: POC:5 B QP 17.00(17)     111520 bits [Y: 45.84 U: 55.08 V: 53.98] [SSIM: 21.096dB] [L0 3 ] [L1 6 ]
x265 [debug]: POC:4 b QP 18.00(18)      84624 bits [Y: 45.47 U: 54.98 V: 53.91] [SSIM: 20.729dB] [L0 3 ] [L1 5 6 ]
x265 [debug]: POC:9 P QP 16.00(16)     187520 bits [Y: 46.65 U: 55.14 V: 54.37] [SSIM: 21.552dB] [L0 6 ]
x265 [debug]: POC:8 B QP 17.00(17)     114376 bits [Y: 45.83 U: 55.09 V: 54.25] [SSIM: 20.881dB] [L0 6 ] [L1 9 ]
x265 [debug]: POC:7 b QP 18.00(18)      76112 bits [Y: 45.51 U: 55.18 V: 54.15] [SSIM: 20.789dB] [L0 6 ] [L1 8 9 ]
[1.7%] 10/590 frames, 7.36 fps, 6185.34 kb/s, eta 0:01:18
```

Do I have to do something else? Is there a way to change any flag and run on debug mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the x265 1.8 from [here](http://x265.ru/en/x265-v-1-8/), `–log-level now controls only console logging, frame level console logging has been removed.` The statistics are shown only in the csv output file using `--csv-log-level 2`.

So I downgrade to x265 1.7 that shows statistics per frame in terminal.